# iOS, PHP and MySQL - No data is written on database

Tags: php, ios, mysql, xcode

I'm creating an iOS App that stores data to an online database using a PHP file and MySQL database.

I managed to make the communication between the iOS app, the PHP file and finally to the database, but no data is written on it, I only know that the communication has been done because the ID field is incremented every time I press the SEND button on the App.

What can be wrong with my code?

Here is my iOS code:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"nome=%@&endereco=%@&telefone=%@&email=%@&mensagem=%@&coordenadas=%@", nome.text, adressLabel.text, telefone.text, email.text, mensagem.text, coordenadas.text];
const char *urlUTF8 = [post UTF8String];
NSString *postBody = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:urlUTF8];

NSData *postData = [postBody dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postDataLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xxxxxxx.com/signup.php"]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postDataLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];
NSLog(@"****** RESPOSTA: %@", content);
```

And the PHP file:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("SERVER","USER","PASS","DATABASE");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo '{"query_result":"ERROR"}';
}

$nome = $_GET['nome'];
$endereco = $_GET['endereco'];
$telefone = $_GET['telefone'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$mensagem = $_GET['mensagem'];
$coordenadas = $_GET['coordenadas'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user (nome, endereco, telefone, email, mensagem, coordenadas) 
      VALUES ('$nome', '$endereco', '$telefone', '$email', '$mensagem', '$coordenadas')");

if($result == true) {
echo '{"query_result":"SUCCESS"}';
}
else{
    echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't work with what I believe to be objective-c so I'm not entirely sure about your first block of code, however, you do appear to be posting data, then in PHP you're attempting to grab data from the global $_GET variable. To debug this try replacing where you're setting your variables with

```
$nome = 'Nome';
$endereco = 'Endereco';
$telefone = 'Telefone';
$email = 'Email';
$mensagem = 'Mensagem';
$coordenadas = 'Coordenadas';
```

This will let you see if it is storing data correctly as it should store the above strings instead of trying to grab the from the global $_GET variable. If this works try replacing the variables with the $_POST variable equivalent:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
$coordenadas = $_POST['coordenadas'];
```

Comment: THANKS! It Worked! I just added "$_POST" like above and now everything is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Because you are using POST method, in php, you use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.